# How to use sass extend in vue 3 vite?

Tags: vue.js, sass, vuejs3, vite

So I imported bootstrap like so in `app.scss` for example,

```
@import "bootstrap/scss/functions";
@import "bootstrap/scss/variables";
@import "bootstrap/scss/mixins";
@import "bootstrap/scss/bootstrap.scss";
```

Now inside a component if I do,

```
<style scoped lang="scss">
.text {
  @extend .text-white;
}
</style>
```

I get the following error,

```
[plugin:vite:css] The target selector was not found.
Use "@extend .text-white !optional" to avoid this error.
  ╷
8 │   @extend .text-white;
  │   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  ╵
  src/components/Navbar.vue 8:3  root stylesheet
```

Answer (score 4):

Add an option to CSS pre-processors in `vite.config.js` :

```
css: {
  preprocessorOptions: {
    scss: {
      additionalData: `@import "bootstrap/scss/bootstrap";`
    }
  }
},
```

[image]

For more info you can check the offical doc at https://vitejs.dev/config/#css-preprocessoroptions

Comment: I don't know if vite does something different than normal vue3 but here are my thoughts: 1) with sass-loader 8, it is called prependData instead of additionalData 2) the additional/prepended data is prepended for every component. Watch the style tags in the head. This can bloat your dom to hell.

Comment: Good comment, if I remember correctly vite doesn't follow this behavior, but I will check and edit the answer accordingly - thanks.